# How to plot 3-D joint density function with uniform distribution in R

Tags: function, plot, 3d, cube

I'm trying to create a 3-d plot of a cube with a shaded column inside it (please see the picture). It's to show the joint pdf within an interval of the following joint density function: f(x,y)=1 where both x and y are between 0 and 1. 
I tried the code below but it gave me an error 'NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments'

```
x <- seq(1,1,length.out=100)
y <- seq(1,1,length.out=100)
df <-expand.grid(x=x,y=y)
df$z <- as.vector(outer(x,y,function(x,y){x*y}))
wireframe(z ~ x*y, data=df, scales=list(arrows=TRUE), zlab='f(x,y)', drape=FALSE)
```

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USz3m.jpg)